# Paypal IPN is showing 404 failure

Tags: php, paypal

I've a form to pay through online checkout in php. It's working good. I can pay sandbox. But the notify_url doesn't works.

```
<input name="notify_url" value="https://myurl.demo" type="hidden"/>
```

It doesn't give me any post data to this url. And in the IPN history log, it's showing 404 error while I can access the url publicly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IPN URL must be reachable from the internet.

Comment: Yes, it's reachable that I mentioned in my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See [the IPN guide](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/ipn/). PayPal does a POST request to the IPN URL, containing the IPN message.

Review your live [IPN history](https://www.paypal.com/merchantnotification/ipn/history) to see a record of the 404s PayPal is receiving. You can test your IPN URL with a sandbox integration. If your IPN URL is not doing anything with the POST data and instead always returning a 404, there is no point to specifying a notify_url value as it will not accomplish anything.

---

As a side note, IPN is very old and practically speaking should be deprecated, no recent PayPal integration should use this feature -- instead use a current [standard PayPal integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) with two routes to create and capture an order.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me what could be the reason the paypal is showing the link 404 ? The link is reachable from the internet. Thanks.

Comment: Your server is returning the 404 when PayPal posts the IPN. Check its logs.